# mmap: enforce 64K alignment

Tags: c++, c, posix

I'm porting a project written (by me) for Windows to mobile platforms.

I need an equivalent of `VirtualAlloc` (+friends), and the natural one is `mmap`. However there are 2 significant differences.

1. Addresses returned by `VirtualAlloc` are guaranteed to be multiples of the so-called *allocation granularity* (`dwAllocationGranularity`). Not to be confused with the page size, this number is arbitrary, and on most Windows system is 64K. In contrast address returned by `mmap` is only guaranteed to be page-aligned.
2. The reserved/allocated region may be freed at once by a call to `VirtualFree`, and there's no need to pass the allocation size (that is, the size used in `VirtualAlloc`). In contrast `munmap` should be given the exact region size to be unmapped, i.e. it frees the given number of memory pages without any relation about how they were allocated.

This imposes problems for me. While I could live with (2), the (1) is a real problem. I don't want to get into details, but assuming the much smaller allocation granularity, such as 4K, will lead to a serious efficiency degradation. This is related to the fact that my code needs to put some information at every granularity boundary within the allocated regions, which impose "gaps" within the contiguous memory region.

I need to solve this. I can think about pretty naive methods of allocating increased regions, so that they can be 64K-aligned and still have adequate size. Or alternatively reserve huge regions of virtual address space, and then allocating properly-aligned memory regions (i.e. implement a sort of an aligned heap). But I wonder if there are alternatives. Such as special APIs, maybe some flags, secret system calls or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) is actually quite easy to solve. As you note, `munmap` takes a size parameter, and this is because `munmap` is capable of *partial* deallocation. You can thus allocate a chunk of memory that is bigger than what you need, then deallocate the parts that aren't aligned.

Comment: This makes sense! It's a shame I didn't figure this out myself :)

Comment: P.S. The drawback here is that in worst-case scenario we'll need 3 syscalls instead of 1: allocation + deallocation at both endings. But this seems to be ok...

Comment: Adding onto this: you can mmap with PROT_NONE to avoid actually allocating memory (basically just reserves an address range). Then after munmap-ing, call mmap again with MAP_FIXED to override your first mapping. Most helpful with anonymous unbacked mappings

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use [`posix_memalign`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) (which despite the name allocates rather than aligns memory); this allows you to specify an alignment, and the memory allocated can be released using `free`. You would need to check whether `posix_memalign` is provided by your target platform.

Comment: Thanks. But I'd prefer to use something portable.

Comment: Another note: `posix_memalign` doesn't guarantee that it will free up the unaligned memory. If they don't free the unaligned memory, you'll be left with significant wastage. For example, `glibc` frees unaligned chunks **unless the allocation was made via `mmap`**, in which case [it only adjusts a pointer](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/malloc/malloc.c#l4441).

Comment: @valdo `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is *less* portable than `posix_memalign`; it isn't even specified by POSIX.

Comment: @nneonneo sure, but you're only wasting address space, which is cheap - the only page you actually hit is the page preceding the allocation, which would have to be hit anyway to store the allocation size.

Comment: @ecatmur: `MAP_ANON` is actually going to be standardized in a future version of POSIX. See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=850#c2305 for the discussion (note that it's been accepted).

Comment: @nneonneo - Actually I'm not going to store the allocated size in the preceding page. I'll deduce it from other parameters in my case.

Comment: The portability is a serious consideration in my case. According to docs, MAP_ANONYMOUSs supported starting from Kernel 2.4. What does this mean regarding modern mobile devices (android, ios)?

Comment: @valdo Android devices mostly use 3.4 or 3.10; even Android 1.0 used Linux 2.6. iOS uses Darwin (a BSD running on XNU) which I'm not sure what it supports.